# Angular Universal express server keeps loading and fails with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-universal

I have an Angular app and I'm trying server-side rendering using Angular universal (https://angular.io/guide/universal) and it doesn't seem to work. I bundle my app and run it through express, I hit http://localhost:4000 and it keeps loading until I see an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from the browser

I've tried pretty much everything but no luck! Any help would be much appreciated

*here are the details of my code*

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "author": "N/A",
  "description": "N/A",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run my-app:server",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^7.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.28",
    "@types/swiper": "^4.4.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "ng-fullcalendar": "^1.7.1",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "replace-in-file": "^3.4.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "swiper": "^4.4.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.4",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.17",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "ts-loader": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule, BrowserTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TransferHttpCacheModule } from '@nguniversal/common';

// Modules
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { ConfigModule } from './configs/config.module';

// Routing
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'my-app'}),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    ConfigModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**src/app/app.server.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

**main.server.ts**

```
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
```

**tsconfig.server.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
...
     "server" : {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }
            ],
            "optimization": true,
            "sourceMap": false
          }
        }
...
```

After these changes, I was able to bundle the browser, server distributions successfully using `ng build --prod && ng run my-app:server`

here's my **server.ts**

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Text'] = win.Text;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['CSS'] = null;
global['Event'] = win.Event;
global['Event']['prototype'] = win.Event.prototype;

Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    };
  },
});

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');
const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

and **webpack.server.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: { server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'none',
  // this makes sure we includes node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [/(node_modules|main(\\|\/)..*(\\|\/).js)/],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for 'WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression'
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    ),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
  ]
};
```

npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr -> http://localhost:4000 -> keeps loading -> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Hi Saad Rashid, Can you solve this issue. If yes please provide a answer.

Comment: Hi Harleen, Yea I solved it after a few more hours of debugging. The underlying problem was with how our angular 7 app was using browser types in some life-cycle hooks. I started from `app.component.ts` and tested each component below it and made my `ngoninit` client specific code to only run if the platform is browser.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you please explain it more?

Comment: Hi Pritam, you should check if there's any browser specific code or API method being used in your application which you are trying to run via Node?

Comment: If you have used browrser types such as `window`, `document`, or `localStorage` etc. You'll need to wrap these in a conditional statement where you make sure they only run when you're angular app is running in a browser 

   `if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // Client only code   
   }`

Comment: Did that. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: No need. I resolved it using what you suggested. Thanks a lot. It will be better if you answer the question yourself.

Comment: One thing I would like to ask you is, how did you configure SSR on your server? Are you using apache? If yes, can you explain in brief?

Comment: I have a separate EC2 instance that serves my angular application, I'm using NGINX as a web server.
All incoming requests coming on port 80 are forwarded to my nodejs app running on port 4000 via NGINX

something like 

`upstream node_app {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://node_app;
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by making sure my angular application is platform agnostic i.e by making browser specific code, browser API methods or browser types such as `window`, `document`, or `localStorage` only run in the browser.

for eg: `if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) { // Client only code }`

Comment: and what happens if platform is not browser? that part inside `if` would never get executed? or is it waited untill platform in browser? this deos not seem to work. Let's say I want to update view on some click and then save some data in local storage. This way the second part is skipped and never gets executed? am I wrong?

Comment: So how do I know where to start. Search my entire codebase for 'window'? How come I don't get an error in the console telling me where I can find the error. This sounds like an insurmountable nightmare for a preexisting application!

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi it never gets executed for a server platform. The SSR for Angular creates a static page where basically NOTHING will work except for routerLink (or A HREF links). It's just HTML. The user sees this view while the JS is loading in the background, so your normal Angular site replaces the static HTML after it's loaded. So click events do literally nothing until the Angular code has loaded. For web crawlers it just takes the HTML and indexes it. By adding `if` statments like this you're just preventing errors during generation of your static HTML.

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi what you asking it is exactly it is happening to me right now, when i use this condition how i will know that js from angular is fullloaded?

Answer (score 1):

To add on to this you also need to wrap `setTimeout` and `location` with the check against the platform browser. I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zainzafar90/51832c3e67a92e12fc0f6e62589ce11a) which should let you see how to set everything up.

Comment: are you sure setTimeout also ? Because I had it run without wrapping it. I wrapped all the location localstorage and window object.